# Recover disk space lost by ZFS after removing an image file dataset

Tags: zfs

I have 1TB drive running zfs on root using ubuntu 21.04.  I was using less than 70GB for my system. I have created (truncated) an image file using 600GB. I used this image file for a different zfs dataset. Then I destroyed the pool and the image file dataset. I have also truncated the image file to 0. I was able to recover about 200GB. I am missing more than 400GB of disc space. zfs reports that I am using 673GB. I do not see more than 70GB used. I do not see any snapshots using so much disk space.

**#zfs list -o space -r rpool**
show that ***rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_ycu6f2*** uses 636GB for snapshots. I cannot find these snapshots.

```
    NAME                                                              AVAIL   USED  USEDSNAP  USEDDS  USEDREFRESERV  USEDCHILD
    rpool                                                              241G   673G        0B     96K             0B       673G
    rpool/ROOT                                                         241G   647G        0B     96K             0B       647G
    rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_ycu6f2                                           241G   647G      636G   3.83G             0B      6.56G
....
```

## zfs list -t snapshot rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_ycu6f2

```
NAME                                       USED  AVAIL     REFER  MOUNTPOINT
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_ycu6f2@autozsys_14wuai   245M      -      637G  -
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_ycu6f2@autozsys_edz0lw   122M      -      637G  -
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_ycu6f2@autozsys_m7el6f   201M      -      637G  -
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_ycu6f2@autozsys_4fi5he   167M      -     4.14G  -
rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_ycu6f2@autozsys_3af8r6   130M      -     4.35G  -
```

How can I find where is the missing disk space and how I can recover it.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the `REFER` column in the `zfs list` output.  Notice that the first three snapshots reference 637G.  The last two snapshots reference only 4.14G and 4.35G, respectively.  It would appear then, that the file(s) you truncated are still referenced in the first three snapshots, but not in the last two.

To reclaim the space, you need to delete the snapshots that predate the moment when you truncated the file(s):

```
sudo zfs destroy -v rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_ycu6f2@autozsys_14wuai
sudo zfs destroy -v rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_ycu6f2@autozsys_edz0lw
sudo zfs destroy -v rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_ycu6f2@autozsys_m7el6f
```

Adding the `-v` option to the `zfs destroy` command line will show you how much space is being freed by each command.  Once you have destroyed those snapshots, you should regain about 633G of free space.

Comment: Yes that was the issue. I still do not understand why "zfs list -t snapshot" did not list these "hidden" snapshots.