# Recover disk space lost by ZFS and Syncoid / Sanoid -- please help

Tags: files, mount, backup, zfs, volume

Long-time reader, first-time poster here. Being new to Linux I've perhaps stupidly (given my level of expertise) allowed it to install with the ZFS file system. This seemed nice initially because it was amazingly easy to do RAID styled striping by adding another drive to the root pool with:

`sudo zpool add rpool /dev/nvme1n1`

However, ZFS has been causing me a gigantic headache for the past two weeks while trying to figure out how to properly back it up. Every online post I can find on ZFS snapshots and replications make backups sound very simple, but they are not for me, probably because I do not understand the fundamental relationship between physical drives, ZFS pools, and snapshots/replications -- were I dealing only with physical drives, I would likely be fine.

After significant research I decided to outsource the problem to Syncoid within the Sanoid program (https://github.com/jimsalterjrs/sanoid/blob/master/README.md#syncoid). This appears to have been a huge mistake. I first set up a pool to contain the backups, which should have taken up only about ~20GB of space. To hold these ~20GB of space on a separate drive labeled "sda" with 28TB of space, I first ran:

`sudo zpool create hdd /dev/sda`

Then using syncoid I tried to backup the root and boot pools to the new "hdd" pool with

`syncoid -r --sendoptions=“vPrF” --no-stream bpool hdd/bpoolbackup`

`syncoid -r --sendoptions=“vPrF” --no-stream rpool hdd/rpoolbackup`

But this ate up 17 TB of space on the hdd pool, leaving only 9 TB left apparently on the physical 28GB HDD. So I destroyed the hdd pool to start over, but this had no effect! When I run fdisk the report actually shows the sda volume only has 9TB of space. This blew my mind as fdisk appears to be subordinate to whatever problem the ZFS file system is causing.

To address this, I searched for the problem and found this StackExchange post [Recover disk space lost by ZFS after removing an image file dataset](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/668631/recover-disk-space-lost-by-zfs-after-removing-an-image-file-dataset) , and following the advice I listed all of the ZFS snapshots and deleted all of them associated with @syncoid. This also has had no effect. So I wanted to unmount the HDD drive "sda" and remount it, thinking this could help. However, when listing the mounted volumes, the sda drive doesn't even appear!

Can someone help me get the drive back into its original shape please? I feel completely lost and of course I completely recognize it's my lack of knowledge that's causing this, but I feel sort of let down by ZFS. It was described as being simple and user friendly, but without a clear connection to physical drives and some direct user control over them, it's quite difficult to use for a novice. I feel like I'm trapped in the matrix with nothing physical to refer to.

As context: I'm not doing anything fancy, just running a Linux machine for personal use. Optimally I don't want any snapshots at all, actually, just a periodic backup of the boot and root directories that will allow me to recover from a catastrophic crash. Everything else is really just a waste of space.

Thanks for any help you can offer!!

New to Linux

Comment: what kind of drive has 28TB of space?    BTW, you may find it easier to understand zfs if you think of a pool as a single drive with one or more partitions ("datasets") on it.   The pool may consist of multiple physical drives, but that doesn't really matter.

Comment: You are asking many questions in one post. You'll get more response if you split it into separate ones: "how do I set up a simple sanoid/syncoid backup?", "how do I reset a hard disc to factory capactity?", "what is a ZFS snapshot?", and so on. You will also need to provide details such as the output of `zpool list`, `zpool status`, `sgdisk --print /dev/hda`. and how you determined that 26TB have gone missing.