# ZFS duplicate datasets

Tags: ubuntu, zfs

I'm getting errors with apt which seems to relate to not enough space on the boot partition. `dpkg --configure -a`

```
Setting up initramfs-tools (0.140ubuntu13) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.140ubuntu13) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-46-generic
...
zstd: error 25 : Write error : No space left on device (cannot write compressed block) 
E: mkinitramfs failure zstd -q -1 -T0 25
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-46-generic with 1.
dpkg: error processing package initramfs-tools (--configure):
 installed initramfs-tools package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 initramfs-tools
```

I've cleaned the partition, but the issue persists.  `du -d1 -h /boot` gives

```
8.2M    /boot/grub
14M /boot/efi
373M    /boot
373M    total
```

`zfs list` yields:

```
bpool                                   1.64G   115M       96K  /boot
bpool/BOOT                              1.63G   115M       96K  none
bpool/BOOT/ubuntu_kd8ik4                 325M   115M      351M  /boot
bpool/BOOT/ubuntu_xwub0c                1.32G   115M      351M  /boot
```

and `zpool status -v bpool`

```
  pool: bpool
 state: ONLINE
  scan: scrub repaired 0B in 00:00:01 with 0 errors on Thu Aug 18 11:10:49 2022
config:

    NAME                                    STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    bpool                                   ONLINE       0     0     0
     ef6a5d5a-29e2-3b47-bd01-cc9b33b50787  ONLINE       0     0     0

errors: No known data errors
```

So now it looks like while the data has been deleted from the partition, it's actually still present in an old snapshot?

However, `zfs list -rt snapshot bpool` shows no large partitions.

```
NAME                                           USED  AVAIL     REFER  MOUNTPOINT
bpool/BOOT/ubuntu_xwub0c@autozsys_g612ij        72K      -      254M  -
bpool/BOOT/ubuntu_xwub0c@autozsys_zz6jnc        56K      -      254M  -
bpool/BOOT/ubuntu_xwub0c@autozsys_37jsph        56K      -      254M  -
bpool/BOOT/ubuntu_xwub0c@autozsys_e1jf32         0B      -      254M  -
bpool/BOOT/ubuntu_xwub0c@autozsys_iediod         0B      -      254M  -
bpool/BOOT/ubuntu_xwub0c@autozsys_kvs9cu         0B      -      254M  -
bpool/BOOT/ubuntu_xwub0c@autozsys_2ljo2e         0B      -      254M  -
bpool/BOOT/ubuntu_xwub0c@autozsys_nuk0ub         0B      -      254M  -
bpool/BOOT/ubuntu_xwub0c@autozsys_ofjed2         0B      -      254M  -
bpool/BOOT/ubuntu_xwub0c@autozsys_wbqse4         0B      -      455M  -
bpool/BOOT/ubuntu_xwub0c@autozsys_x820pz         0B      -      455M  -
bpool/BOOT/ubuntu_xwub0c@autozsys_wwx7np         0B      -      455M  -
bpool/BOOT/ubuntu_xwub0c@autozsys_fhi1tz        72K      -      341M  -
bpool/BOOT/ubuntu_xwub0c@autozsys_8jj3zu        64K      -      341M  -
bpool/BOOT/ubuntu_xwub0c@autozsys_bfdhhr         0B      -      341M  -
bpool/BOOT/ubuntu_xwub0c@autozsys_95dnyh         0B      -      341M  -
bpool/BOOT/ubuntu_xwub0c@autozsys_7orem7        64K      -      341M  -
bpool/BOOT/ubuntu_xwub0c@autozsys_5rpfzz        72K      -      351M  -
bpool/BOOT/ubuntu_xwub0c@autozsys_1npt7j         0B      -      351M  -
bpool/BOOT/ubuntu_xwub0c@autozsys_uevq0m         0B      -      351M  -
```

Any ideas?  Maybe also help me understand what I'm looking at here.  If these are not snapshots, what are they and how do I consolidate them?

**Edit**
`zfs list -o name,used,usedsnap -s usedsnap bpool`

```
NAME    USED  USEDSNAP
bpool  1.64G        0B
```

Comment: Your question may be a duplicate of [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/668631/recover-disk-space-lost-by-zfs-after-removing-an-image-file-dataset/668872#668872).  Does the answer there help you?  In short, yes, those are snapshots.  And yes, certain of those snapshots will need to be destroyed in order to regain your free disk space.

Comment: If you would, please [edit] your post and include the output of: `zfs list -o name,used,usedsnap -s usedsnap bpool`.  That will show you how much space the dataset is using, and of that, how much is used by snapshots.

Comment: My question wasn't specific enough.  I meant are the two lines at the output of `zfs list` snapshots? The ones that end in ubuntu_kd8ik4 and ubuntu_xwub0c?  The output of @JimL. 's question seems to indicate otherwise.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to the other question, @JimL.  I'll read it again, but at first glance none of the snapshots for bpool reference the 1.6GB dataset (?) that zfs lists. How do I know which snapshots are safe to destroy?  How can I tell which are the old ones and which the new?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR:

Get with the man page: `man zfs`

Set up a "test pool" on a different drive, and learn about snapshots and filesystems on that pool, so that you won't be worried about doing something to your system-critical pools.

Make friends with `zfs list` so you know whether you're looking at
filesystems or snapshots: `zfs list -rt filesystem` / `zfs list -rt snapshot'

Make friends with `zfs get` so you know how to display the various properties
of a filesystem or snapshot: `zfs get all`

Finally, devise a backup strategy for your snapshots and identify which snapshots you want to keep, and which you don't.  Do a `zfs destroy -v ....` on the snapshots you don't want.

---

For learning how to work with ZFS datasets, it's a worthwhile effort to read the `zfs` man page.  ZFS datasets have numerous properties, depending on whether you're working with a dataset, a snapshot, a volume, etc.

For starters,

> zfs list [-r|-d depth] [-Hp] [-o property[,property]...] [-s
> property]... [-S property]... [-t type[,type]...]
> [filesystem|volume|snapshot]...
>
> Lists the property information for the given datasets in tabular form.
> If specified, you can list property information by the absolute
> pathname or the relative pathname.  By default, all file systems and
> volumes are displayed.  Snapshots are displayed if the listsnaps
> property is on (the default is off).  The following fields are
> displayed, name,used,available,referenced,mountpoint.

If you're not clear whether the entries you're looking at are filesystems or snapshots, you can tell `zfs` to display only the type you want to see.  To see only filesystems, use:

```
zfs list -rt filesystem bpool
```

To see only snapshots, use:

```
zfs list -rt snapshot bpool
```

To see both, try:

```
zfs list -rt all -o name,type,creation
```

You may be able to improve the clarity of your filesystem layout by choosing filesystem and snapshot names more descriptively.  I generally name snapshots based on YYYYMMDD-HHMMSS, so I can quickly see that a snapshot named `poolname/var/db@20220817-000500` is a snapshot of the `/var/db` filesystem, and is newer than the snapshot named `poolname/var/db@20220815-000500`.

The `creation` property can be queried to have `zfs` display the datestamp of when the snapshot was created:

```
$ zfs get creation poolname/var/db@20220817-000500
NAME                             PROPERTY  VALUE                  SOURCE
poolname/var/db@20220817-000500  creation  Wed Aug 17  0:05 2022  -
```

or to display the name and creation of all snapshots of the `poolname/var/db` dataset:

```
$ zfs list -rt snap -o name,creation poolname/var/db
NAME                                    CREATION
poolname/var/db@20220812-000500         Fri Aug 12  0:05 2022
poolname/var/db@prior-to-installworld   Fri Aug 12 12:13 2022
poolname/var/db@20220813-000500         Sat Aug 13  0:05 2022
poolname/var/db@20220814-000500         Sun Aug 14  0:05 2022
poolname/var/db@20220815-000500         Mon Aug 15  0:05 2022
poolname/var/db@20220816-000500         Tue Aug 16  0:05 2022
poolname/var/db@20220817-000500         Wed Aug 17  0:05 2022
poolname/var/db@prior-to-installkernel  Wed Aug 17 12:54 2022
poolname/var/db@20220818-000500         Thu Aug 18  0:05 2022
poolname/var/db@20220819-000500         Fri Aug 19  0:05 2022
```

To see an example of the properties ZFS stores for a filesystem, try:

```
zfs get all bpool
```

Once you get the hang of which properties are useful in your workflow, you can tweak the `-o` part of `zfs list -rt all -o name,type,creation` to list those properties.

As for your question about which snapshots are safe to delete, by definition
all **snapshots** are safe to delete.  They're snapshots, not filesystems.
(Beware though that `zfs` won't let you destroy a snapshot if it is the
origin of a cloned filesystem.) As with any backup strategy, you should
intentionally plan out how often you want to take snapshots, and how long you
want to store them.  There will generally be a time when the age of the
snapshot grows to a point where the snapshot is no longer valuable as a
backup point, because so much has changed that it would be painful to revert
that far back.  Once snapshots reach that age, it's prudent to routinely
purge them to recover the pool space used by the snapshots.  This is another case where the use of meaningful, intelligible snapshot names can help sort out which snapshots are important to you, and which snapshots are not.  But the subject of backup strategies is a whole 'nother kettle of fish....

When you've identified a snapshot that you want to destroy, you can copy-and-paste the name into the command line:

```
zfs destroy -v bpool/BOOT/ubuntu_xwub0c@autozsys_g612ij
```

Lastly, I wasn't specific enough with the `USEDSNAP` property I requested.  But if you do:

```
zfs list -o name,used,usedsnap bpool/BOOT/ubuntu_xwub0c
```

you should see how much space is used by that dataset in total, and how much of that space is being taken up by the snapshots.

I hope this helps you get started with reading the `zfs` man page and learning about how to query the ZFS system to get the information you're after.

Comment: Thanks.  The term I was looking for is clones.  I don't know why I had a clone of the FS, but I've managed to remove it.  Also, although the snapshots show very little used space, removing them one by one ended up clearing about 1Gb of space on my boot partition, which resolved my issues.  Thanks for the help.